# How can would I translate this array of JS objects into an array of Swift tuples?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I'm trying to structure my data in Swift and I'm having a hard time initializing an the empty array of nested tuples and arrays.
I'm new to Swift, very familiar with JS.
Here is how my data would be structured in JS:

```
let data = [] // Loop will push objects into this variable

// This is the object that would be pushed into data from within a loop - for range in ranges
ranges.forEach(range => {
    data.push({
        [range]: {
            'minDate': Date(),
            'minDateText': '',
            'tags': [{
                'name': '',
                'color': '',
                'total': ''
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried a few different things in swift, but I'm just not getting it. Seems like you have to have an exact representation of the array before its actually holding any data. I need to initialize it without any data.

The latest thing I've tried is this:

```
var data:[(String:(String:Date, String:String, String:[(String:String, String:String, String:String)]))] = [] 
// Get error "Cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop thinking how to code in JS and start reading about how to code in Swift. You can start with [Apple Swift book](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewBook?id=1002622538), it covers almost everything you need to get started. So what you really need is to structure your data:

```
struct Object {
    let minDate: Date
    let minDateText: String
    let tags: [Tag]
}

struct Tag {
    let name: String
    let color: String
    let total: String
}
```

Then you can create a dictionary or an array with it:

```
var dictionary: [String: Object] = [:]
var objects: [Object] = []
```